# Laravel 5.7 doesn't generate HTTPS routes if the webserver has no encryption layer installed

Tags: laravel, ssl, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.7

The current server setup looks like this.

A server with an nginx reverse proxy pointing to multiple docker containers.
Our Laravel 5.7 application runs in one of these containers with nginx + php7.2 FPM

The webserver inside docker should hand an INSECURE response to the reverse proxy which makes it SECURE on the outer layer.

The containerized webserver listens on 80.

All URLs generated by Laravel are HTTP even though the protocol is explicitly specified to be HTTPS in the config/app.php APP_URL setting.

I've also tried a couple of other tricks, sslizing middleware and such but none of them seem to work.

Any idea?

Comment: Normally to match the protocol that arrives on the proxy, the proxy itself must set either the `X-Forwarded-Proto=https` or the `Forwarded` header as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded. Without those Laravel will assume the unforwarded protocol to be the correct one and that is http.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should fill `$proxies` property in `TrustProxies` middleware https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php for example:

```
protected $proxies = [
  'ip1',
   'ip2',
];
```

You can read more about it in [Configure Trusted proxies section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

Comment: @RápliAndrás I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` as reverse proxy for my Docker containers and I didn't have to set anything manually. The only thing I had to do it adding my ip into this array.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do it with `TrustProxies` and modifying the nginx config. I'll leave here the corresponding proxy settings if it helps someone in the future:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header   X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;
```

Comment: I'm using jwilder/nginx-proxy with letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion on laravel 6.2 application and none of the solutions are working for me. I tried adding the remote_addr in the proxies array, I tried setting the proper headers in nginx config, all without any success. Any other ideas, guys?Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks!